# jQuery popup from mysql data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquerynew.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() 
        {       
             $('.wings').click(function(event) 
   {
       $(this).next('.popupbox').fadeIn();
       $('body').css('background','#333');        
   });

       $('.popupclose').click(function(event) 
       {            
           unloadPopupBox();
           $('body').css('background','white');
       });

       function loadPopupBox() 
       {  
          $('.popupbox').fadeIn("slow");
       }        

       function unloadPopupBox() 
       {
          $('.popupbox').fadeOut("normal");       
       }  
       $(".popupbox").hide();
    });

</script>

<style>
 table { border-collapse:collapse; margin-left:370px; margin-top:20px; padding:10px; font-family:Trebuchet MS; min-width:530px; }
 table th,td { border:1px solid #8AC007; }

 .popupbox {  position:fixed; _position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6 */ background:#FFFFFF; left:0px; top:150px; 
           border:2px solid lightgray; padding:15px;  z-index:100px; font-size:15px;  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px lightgray; 
           -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px lightgray; box-shadow: 0 0 5px lightgray; display:none; }

 .popupclose { border:0px solid lightgray; color:#6FA5E2; font-family:verdana; font-weight:bold; line-height:15px; float:right;
               cursor:pointer;  text-decoration:none; }
</style>

<?php

  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  
  mysql_select_db("popupsql",$con);

  $users = mysql_query("SELECT u.id, u.username, u.firstname, u.lastname FROM lms_user u");  
  $rows = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($users))
  $rows[] = $row;

  echo '<table>
             <tr style="background:#8AC007;color:#8A4C25;font-size:15px;">
                <th style="padding:10px;">Firstname</th>
                <th style="padding:10px;">Lastname</th>
                <th style="padding:10px;">Status</th>
             </tr>';
  foreach($rows as $row)
  { 
     $userid = $row['id'];
     echo '<tr>
               <td style="padding:5px;">'.$row['firstname'].'</td>
               <td style="padding:5px;">'.$row['lastname'].'</td>
               <td style="padding:5px;text-align:center;">
                 <a class="wings">view status&nbsp;'.$userid.'</a>
                 <div class="popupbox">
                     <div style="height:30px;"><img class="popupclose" src="close.png" style="float:right;"></img></div>';
                     $grades = mysql_query('SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email, ggh.finalgrade, gi.itemname FROM lms_grade_grades_history ggh, 
                                           lms_grade_items gi, lms_user u WHERE ggh.itemid = gi.id AND gi.itemtype = "course" AND u.id = ggh.userid 
                                           AND u.id = '.$userid.'');                     
                     $rows = array();
                     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($grades));
                     $rows[] = $row;
                     foreach($rows as $row)
                     {
                       echo 'SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email, ggh.finalgrade, gi.itemname FROM lms_grade_grades_history ggh, 
                                           lms_grade_items gi, lms_user u WHERE ggh.itemid = gi.id AND gi.itemtype = "course" AND u.id = ggh.userid 
                                           AND u.id = '.$userid.'';
                     }
                 echo '</div>
               </td>
           </tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';


?>
```

Here is my code for displaying jQuery popup dynamically from mysql database., a popup is displaying for all the rows but not displaying with a same id i.e., a correct id wasn't passing to a popup window. Can anyone suggest me.

Comment: try to simplify the code as much as possible. I'm sure the issue has nothing to do i.e. with your CSS.

Comment: First of all, please concatinate all the strings and make concatination proper "string" . $stringvar. Also, I would keep the other mysql query out of foreach loop since it does not seem to be connected to $row. If all the data is not passed correctly, check for all PHP errors (in log for one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Never use same `ID` for different elements!

You are just loading and unloading the same `popupBox`. All the popupboxes have same `ID` and that is wrong. Also, there is **no** `#popupbox` in your HTML. In your script, change this way:

```
   $('.wings').click(function(event) 
   {
       $(this).next('.popupbox').fadeIn();
       $('body').css('background','#333');        
   });
```

And change all the `#wings` and `#popupbox` to classes by changing to `.wings` and `.popupbox`. Also update the HTML to use `class="wings"` and `class="popupbox"`.

**Explanation**

The `$(this).next('.popupbox')` will select the `.popupbox` next to the link, which is being clicked. So, you will be clicking a link and the `.popupbox` next to the link will be shown. Hope this is clear.

Comment: Yes.. I agree.. and this is my edited code even now i couldn't pass a correct userid to a popup window

Comment: jQuery does it @ronbosc, You don't need to pass anything. You can get it from `href` using `.attr('href')`

Comment: @ronbosc You haven't changed it right. Remove the `loadPopupBox()` completely and replace it with my code.

Comment: Thank You, that was working fine with your code. But could explain me the meaning of   $(this).next('.popupbox').fadeIn(); what next() do here

Comment: @ronbosc Added the explanation.

Comment: Thank You for your kind explanation praveen kumar